# URL rewrite is not working in Apache Server properly

Tags: php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ $1.php  [L,QSA]
```

this is my link `domain.com/new.php`

url is rewriting but the page is not running ...
it is throwing an error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /domin.com/new was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache Server at domain.com Port 80

Comment: Did you specify those lines in Virtual Host / Server configuration or in an .htaccess file?

Comment: yes,I placed .htaccess file in the directory where i am running the code

Comment: Is this the root-directory of your domain (i.e. your request URI is "/new") or is it nested inside a sub-directory (i.e. your request URI is like "/subdir/new"). In the latter case, you must set `RewriteBase` appropriately.

Comment: yes, Actually I tried to run in the subdir but it is not done... it is not even running in my root dir also

Comment: so /domin.com/new or /domain.com/new ?

Comment: domain.com/new.php is my file ..... by using the url rewrite I actually getting domain.com/new but the file is not running

Answer (score 0):

Try like this otherwise you have issue with apache rewrite.  Rule added by you is also correct.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^new?$ new.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that apache rewrite is not enabled in your server. Run this through SSH to enable it:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart Apache Service:

```
service apache2 restart
```

If this doesn't help, it could be that your server is not allowing your htaccess file. To solve this, edit this file: /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.

Look for:

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
            # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
            #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
    </Directory>
```

Change:

```
AllowOverride None
```

To:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Then restart Apache again.

Also, I have had this issue once where apache user (www-data) was not given permission on that particular site. Just an extra hint.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try this it worked for me add these lines in your .htaccess root directory or copy go to cpanel your domain Public_html folder,enable show hidden files, goto .htaccess file and paste this command lines :


Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then restart your Apache or PHP-FPM (Optional)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Replacing one rule with the entire file content of your .htaccess file seems like breaking a butterfly on a wheel.

Answer (score -3):

Dont forget even if you do perfect

you have to make the link like this

`<li><a href="new">new</a></li>`

you should remove the `.php` extension from the link

Comment: This does not answer his question. As he already stated `The requested URL /domin.com/new was not found on this server.` in his question, this answer is pointless.